# How do I get VSTS to build each branch into it's own drop folder

Tags: azure-devops, branch, release-management

I would like to setup my pipeline in release management to use drops from Dev branch and UAT to use drops from master branch but not sure how to set this up as it seems they both write to the one location'drop'

Comment: Do you solve this issue? –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to these steps below:

1. Click +Add to add artifacts
2. Choose Git source type
3. Specify repository and branch and change Source alias to {repository name}-{branch}
4. Repeat 1-3 to add another branch